# Connecting to couch db from a webpage

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb

I used to use mysql databases and a php backend for my web applications. Now that I am diving deeper into the the javascript world I am looking for a more compatible way to store my data. I like the idea of writing everything in one language, and javascript seems to be capable to make that job.
I started reading about couchDB and the JSON/javaScipt approach seems to fit perfectly to my needs. My question is now, which would be a convenient way to connect to the database from my pages.

I found this [post](http://jan.prima.de/~jan/plok/archives/108-Programming-CouchDB-with-Javascript.html), which explains how to connect to a couchDB directly from a client-side javascript using a library called couch.js. The post is quite a few years old and the library I cannot find anywhere in the web. So I am asking myself If this approach is still up to date.

I was thought that one important reason for using a server backend is to provide a security mechanism to protect the database authentification process. So: Is it generally secure to save an (encrypted) db pwd in a client side script?

So what I am looking for is a quite simple way to access and store json-like data from webpages. Are there any suggestions?
The hosting of the production solution should also be not that difficult and in the end not expansive, since it's rather meant for smaller projects at the moment.

If the post does not fit to the forum, let me know a better place for it..

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the CouchDB jQuery Plugin for development. At first I was hesitant as well to use it due to most documentation being at least a few years old. So far it has worked really well and been very easy to use, especially if you are familiar with JavaScript/jQuery.

...

You can get the plugin from Github

[CouchDB jQuery Plugin](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-jquery-couch)

Or you can save it directly from Futon:

http://localhost:5984/_utils/script/jquery.couch.js (where local host is your IP and 5984 is the port CouchDB is on)

Whatever you do, make sure you enable CORS on your database. There are instructions on the Github Readme page, or [this script](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb) is super useful and easy to use through npm.

...

Documentation can be found [here](http://daleharvey.github.io/jquery.couch.js-docs/symbols/).

[This reference](http://bradley-holt.com/2011/07/couchdb-jquery-plugin-reference/) has also been very useful for me.

...

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the hints.. the couch.js that I was looking for is also stored inside _utils/script folder. As far as I get it now, there are no cross server requests possible. Where do you store your html, js, css docs? As couch document attachments (would force me to use couchapp, which I want to avoid at the moment) or inside the built in server? Unfortunately I cannot find it's document root directory...

Comment: I am running my website on an Apache web server, so all my html, js, and css are in the regular www folder for that. To get cross server requests you need to enable CORS. So you can send there requests:    
curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_config/httpd/enable_cors -d '"true"'; curl -X PUT http://localhost:5984/_config/cors/origins -d '"*"';    Or run this [script](https://github.com/pouchdb/add-cors-to-couchdb).

Answer (score 0):

I just released [Slouch](https://github.com/redgeoff/slouch), a JavaScript client for CouchDB that can be used in both the browser and in node. I hope this helps!